# Запрашиваем файл по относительному пути, а отдаем со второго сайта

Tags: php, nginx, apache

Что необходимо выполнить, чтобы на втором сайте.
На котором указаны относительные пути к файлам, а самих файлов на данном сайте нету.
Пользователю отдавала ответ, к примеру изображение которое храниться на первом сайте.

Comment: через cURL отправляем запрос получаем ответ, если 200 то показываем изображение, ну а если 404 то логично - файла не существует...

Comment: А по умолчанию возможно в конфиге nginx выполнить так, чтобы все статичные файлы он отдавал со второго сайта?

Comment: Url которые указаны в относительных путях,...

Comment: оба сайта расположены на одном сервре, то есть возможно через nginx настроить так, чтобы статичные файлы он брал из второго сайта, локально...

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конфиге Nginx для первого и второго сайта разделите блоки server и в конфиге второго возпользуйтесь директивой try_files:

```
server {
    ...
     server_name site1.ru;
    ...
}

server {
    ... 
    server_name site2.ru;

    try_files $uri @proxying_to_site1;

    location @proxying_to_site1 {
        proxy_set_header Host site1.ru;
        proxy_pass http://site1.ru;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1443421/Правка-конфига-nginx-хранение-файлов-на-другом-сайте

Comment: если не ошибаюсь, это тот конфиг того сайта, на котором необходимо внести изменения