# Правка конфига nginx, хранение файлов на другом сайте

Tags: nginx

Есть 2 сайт, на втором сайте указаны относительные пути '/path/file.txt'

Необходимо чтобы все файлы к котором есть запросы по относительным путям, чтобы nginx брал их с 1 сайта, оба сата расположены на локальном сервере под 1 пользователем.

Расположение конфига для сайта, если я не ошибаюсь
/etc/nginx/vhosts/user/site.ru

```
server {
    server_name site.su www.site.su;
    charset off;
    index index.php;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-resources/site.su/*.conf;
    access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/site.su.access.log;
    error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/site.su.error.log notice;
    ssi on;
    return 301 https://$host:443$request_uri;
    set $root_path /var/www/user/data/www/embed;
    root $root_path;
    location / {
        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
        }
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
        }
        location / {
            try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
        }
    }
    location @fallback {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
        proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8081 /;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        access_log off;
    }
    listen 61.104.11.42:80;
}
server {
    server_name site.su www.site.su;
    ssl_certificate "/var/www/httpd-cert/user/site.su_le1.crtca";
    ssl_certificate_key "/var/www/httpd-cert/user/site.su_le1.key";
    ssl_ciphers EECDH:+AES256:-3DES:RSA+AES:!NULL:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam4096.pem;
    charset off;
    index index.php;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-resources/site.su/*.conf;
    access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/site.su.access.log;
    error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/site.su.error.log notice;
    ssi on;
    set $root_path /var/www/user/data/www/embed;
    root $root_path;
    location / {
        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
        }
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
        }
        location / {
            try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
        }
    }
    location @fallback {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
        proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8081 /;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        access_log off;
    }
    listen 61.104.11.42:443 ssl http2;
}
```

Не понимаю, что именно необходимо поправить, как верно указать путь? Учитывая опыт методом проб, тыка, у меня снова сайт перестанет работать. Кто подскажет что именно необходимо поправить, какой url быдет?

Answer (score 1):

Какой будет урл решать вам и вашему приложению, а конфиг Nginx составляется для того чтобы правильно обработать запросы нужных вам урлов.

Чтобы проксировать запрос несуществующего файла site.su/path/file.txt на http://127.0.0.1:8081/path/file.txt в обоих блоках server замените:

```
        location / {
            try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
        }
```

на

```
        location / {
            try_files $uri @fallback;
        }
```

И из`location @fallback` уберите директиву `proxy_redirect`.

Comment: стрчку proxy_redirect удалил в обеих блоках.  ' try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;'  заменил на 'try_files $uri @fallback;'. А вот с url не совсем понимал. site1.su и site2.su расположены в одном каталоге. Каким верным будет url? То есть необходимо указать как то так:  'try_files /../site1.ru/$uri @fallback;' или так  'try_files /site1.ru/$uri @fallback;' не работает. Не понимаю, от какой директории он начинает читать, от той в каталоге котором расположены сайты?

Comment: все пути указываются относительно пути, указанного в директиве root

Comment: в вашем случае могут быть 2 подхода: первый скорректировал для вас я. Он заключается в проксировании запроса на другой сервер и не зависит от физического места нахождения файлов. Они могут находится даже на другом конце света

Comment: вы при этом хотите примешать в конфиг другой подход исходя из того что файлы у вас на одном сервере в разных папках. Тогда вам не нужно проксирование вовсе. Вам нужно только правильно указать root директиву и в проксировании нет необходимости